# Progress bar repeating percentages

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I developed a responsive progress bar, however the progress values ​​are repeated. Only the central value should appear.

Does anyone know how I can solve this?

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y5mzhm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

```
 <div id="tab1">
      <dx-data-grid class="tableTask" [dataSource]="datas" [showColumnLines]="false"
        [showRowLines]="false" [columnAutoWidth]="true" [allowColumnResizing]="false">
        <dxo-header-filter [visible]="true"></dxo-header-filter>
        <dxo-remote-operations [sorting]="true" [paging]="true" [filtering]="true"></dxo-remote-operations>
        <dxo-paging [pageSize]="200"></dxo-paging>
        <dxi-column dataField="id" caption="ID" [width]="100" [allowFiltering]="false" [allowSorting]="false"></dxi-column>
        <dxi-column dataField="name" caption="Name"></dxi-column>
        <dxi-column dataField="surname" caption="Surname"></dxi-column>
           <dxi-column dataField="progress" cellTemplate="Progress" caption="Progress"></dxi-column>
            <div *dxTemplate="let data of 'Progress'">
          <div style="top:4px" class="progress aqua" [attr.data-width]="percentage" (mousedown)="updateSlider($event,data)">
            <div class="progress-text">{{data.key.progress}} %</div>
            <div class="progress-bar" [style.width]="data.key.progress + '%'">
              <div class="progress-text">{{data.key.progress}} %</div>
            </div>
          </div>
            </div>
      </dx-data-grid>
    </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I removed the **percent value** inside the **progress bar** and added **z-index**.

This should do the trick :

```
 <div id="tab1">
      <dx-data-grid class="tableTask" [dataSource]="datas" [showColumnLines]="false"
        [showRowLines]="false" [columnAutoWidth]="true" [allowColumnResizing]="false">
        <dxo-header-filter [visible]="true"></dxo-header-filter>
        <dxo-remote-operations [sorting]="true" [paging]="true" [filtering]="true"></dxo-remote-operations>
        <dxo-paging [pageSize]="200"></dxo-paging>
        <dxi-column dataField="id" caption="ID" [width]="100" [allowFiltering]="false" [allowSorting]="false"></dxi-column>
        <dxi-column dataField="name" caption="Name"></dxi-column>
        <dxi-column dataField="surname" caption="Surname"></dxi-column>
           <dxi-column dataField="progress" cellTemplate="Progress" caption="Progress"></dxi-column>
            <div *dxTemplate="let data of 'Progress'">
          <div style="top:4px" class="progress aqua" [attr.data-width]="percentage" (mousedown)="updateSlider($event,data)">
            <div class="progress-text" style="z-index:2">{{data.key.progress}} %</div>
            <div class="progress-bar" style="z-index:1" [style.width]="data.key.progress + '%'">
            </div>
          </div>
            </div>
      </dx-data-grid>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove this line `<div class="progress-text">{{data.key.progress}} %</div>` from below code for bar % the white one, and remove `<div class="progress-text">{{data.key.progress}} %</div>` inside `progress-bar` for bar %

```
<div style="top:4px" class="progress aqua" [attr.data-width]="percentage" (mousedown)="updateSlider($event,data)">
            <div class="progress-text">{{data.key.progress}} %</div>
            <div class="progress-bar" [style.width]="data.key.progress + '%'">
              <div class="progress-text">{{data.key.progress}} %</div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to just display the white text.

In order to do that, you need to remove line 15 in `app.component.html` file and add a large z-index to class `progress-text`